# Bring Drop down label, drop down and submit button in a same line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a rails application and i am having a drop down submit form as below,

```
#container
  = form_tag({:controller => "r4d", :action=> "result" }, remote: true, method: :get) do
      = label_tag(:q, "Trip Type: ")
      = select_tag(:q, options_for_select(r4d_options, "r4d_002"), class: "form-control")
      = submit_tag("Get Trip Details", :id => "submit", :class => "btn btn-sm btn-default")
```

The problem here is, the drop down label appears in an line followed by drop down and submit button in an another line. How can i make this appear in same line. I am using bootstrap scss.

Thanks for your help.

Based on the below answer, i have changed the code to

```
= form_tag({:controller => "r4d", :action => "result", :class => "form-inline"}, remote: true, method: :get) do
    .row
        .col-sm-12
            .col-sm-4
                = label_tag(:q, "Trip Type: ")
            .col-sm-4
                = select_tag(:q, options_for_select(r4d_options), class: "form-control")
            .col-sm-4
                = submit_tag("Get Trip Details", :id => "submit", :class => "btn btn-sm btn-default")
```

but there are too much spacing between the form elements and it doesn't looks good.

Comment: Can you please screen shot  ? how it looks and how you want ?

Comment: @Vishal I have added the image and i need that to be in same line

Comment: are you using bootstrap in your application ?

Comment: yes. I am using it

Comment: Please try my answer, let me know if it is working or not

Comment: Did you checked my answer properly ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using haml please try below format for set content in one row

```
  .row
    .col-sm-12
      .col-sm-6
        = label_tag(:q, "Trip Type: ")
        = select_tag(:q, options_for_select(r4d_options, "r4d_002"), class: "form-control")
      .col-sm-6
        = submit_tag("Get Trip Details", :id => "submit", :class => "btn btn-sm btn-default")
```

Comment: Its still in the left side as earlier with some margin. Is there any way to do this by adding class names alone?

Comment: @santhoshkumar check whether bootstrap css is applying or not .

Comment: bootstrap css is getting applied. I am not using any other .row or .col in my css.scss

Comment: @santhoshkumar if width css of col-sm-12 and col-sm-6 is applying than there should be no problem.

Comment: i have changed that to col-sm-4 from col-sm-4. But there are too many spacing between the webelements and it doesnt looks good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170064/discussion-between-vishal-and-santhosh-kumar).

Comment: Hi, are you available now?

Comment: Yes.. please ask

Comment: I was waiting for you on chat room